# Trying to call getUserMedia from a frame without correct 'allow' attribute, In safari

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, safari, frontend

I'm trying to access the camera and microphone on the framed site (using ReactJS) but it throws this error on safari (Chrome and Firefox are working).

**Both the host and the frame are using HTTPS.**

```
<iframe allow="camera *; microphone *" src="test.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it gives me this error on desktop, but on a real device the issue is no longer exsists